# How to replace phonenumber by name for incoming calls in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've saved contacts on a server in an uncommom format. These contacts are regularly evaluated and changed. Using a xamarin app on my android device I want to synchrously connect a phonenumber to a name.

Using a BroadcastReceiver that captures all incoming call I'm able to display a toast and a notification showing the name related to the number.

Because the toast disappear fast and the notification isn't easy available during ringing I search for another way to display the name connected to a number. The best way would be to replace the displayed number on the dialer.

Comment: I do not think you can do that, why don't you display an alert? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android-using-xamarin

Comment: I think an alert is only an intern notification. But, what I haven't mentioned in my question, is that my application isn't all the time in the foreground.